# repeater Button event in formview asp.net

Tags: repeater, formview

ItemCommand contains RepeaterCommandEventArgs which has two important fields:

CommandName

CommandArgument

how to get Button event,get asp:DropDownList select values

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" id="fwHotelDetails" DataKeyNames="id" OnDataBound="fwHotelDetails_DataBound" OnModeChanging="fwHotelDetails_ModeChanging" >
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="repScore">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlnumber" runat="server">
                                                    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:LinkButton ID="saveButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id")%>' Text="Edit" />
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <EditItemTemplate>
             Test test, anything??
        </EditItemTemplate>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RepeaterCommandEventArgs` argument contains a property called `Item`. From this property you can access the method `FindControl()`.

So your code would look like this:

```
void repScore_ItemCommand(Object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) { 
   DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlNumber");
   string selectedValue = ddl.SelectedValue;
}
```

Also, don't forget to wire up your repeater to handle the event:

```
<asp:Repeater ... OnItemCommand="repScore_ItemCommand" .... >
```

Comment: but Repeater  in side the asp:FormView

Comment: Why is that an issue? Am I missing something here?